# AJAX function connecting to PHP on same page error

Tags: php, ajax, validation, forms

I have built an AJAX function that links to some PHP on the same page. The PHP worked fine but with the AJAX function there is an error and the validation is not taking place.

The AJAX

```
function contact() {
    var ENQemail = $('#ENQemail').val();
    var ENQfirstname = $('#ENQfirst_name').val();
    var ENQlastname = $('#ENQlast_name').val();
    var ENQmessage = $('#ENQmessage').val();
    var ENQsecword = $('#ENQsecword').val();


    var dataString = 'ENQemail=' + ENQemail + '&ENQfirstname=' + ENQfirstname + '&ENQlastname=' + ENQlastname + '&ENQmessage=' + ENQmessage + '&ENQsecword=' + ENQsecword;

    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
             url: 'http://www.divethegap.com/update/contact',
             data: dataString,

                 dataType:'json',
             success: function(data) {
     $('#ERRemail').html(data.ERRemail);
     $('#ERRfirstname').html(data.ERRfirstname);
     $('#ERRlastname').html(data.ERRlastname);
     $('#ERRmessage').html(data.ERRmessage);
     $('#ERRsecword').html(data.secword);
     $("#enquiry").effect("shake", { times:4 }, 100);
},
      error: function() {
          $("#enquiry").effect("shake", { times:4 }, 100);
                 },


        });

}
```

Could it be that one cannot have the PHP on the same page when using AJAX.

Any ideas,

Marvellous

Comment: And what is the error? Have you tried to use a relative URL, i.e. `'/update/contact'`?

Comment: what is your php supposed to return to Ajax function(data) ?

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good idea to encode request parameters.  This may or may not be the source of your problem:

```
var dataString = 'ENQemail=' + encodeURIComponent(ENQemail) + '&ENQfirstname=' + encodeURIComponent(ENQfirstname) + '...';
```

Also, it looks like you are telling the AJAX function to send a JSON message (`dataType:'json'`).  However, the data you are passing into it is not a JSON message.